# WPF - Is there a way to set the time when selecting a date in a DatePicker?

Tags: wpf, datetime, datepicker

I have a DatePicker and bound the SelectedDate to a DateTime. The problem is that this SelectedDate always gives me the time as 0:00:00. Is there a way to choose a default?

I was thinking of use DateTime.AddHour().AddMinutes(), but I would like something that does not depends of the current time of that DateTime.

Comment: Why don't you set the SelectedDate to a specific DateTime when you instantiate your view model?

Comment: But is is a DatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you do something like that :

```
DateTime yourNewDateTime = new DateTime(datePickerDateTime.Year,
                                        datePickerDateTime.Month,
                                        datePickerDateTime.Day,
                                        YOUR_DEFAULT_DATETIME_HOUR,
                                        YOUR_DEFAULT_DATETIME_MINUTES,
                                        YOUR_DEFAULT_DATETIME_SECONDS);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Have a get that adds time

```
private DateTime? dt;
public DateTime? Dt 
{ 
    get { return dt; } 
    set 
    {
        if (dt == value) return;
        dt = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DtTime");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Dt");
    } 
}
public DateTime? DtTime
{
    get
    {
        if (dt == null) return null;
        return ((DateTime)dt).AddHours(6.0);
    }
}
```